# L is normal extension if it's splitting field

Tags: extension-field, splitting-field

I am trying to understand this proof That if L is splitting field of some polynomial then it's normal extension .

[image]

I got the part till we get that $L(\alpha)/K(\alpha)$ and $L(\beta )/K(\beta)$ are isomorphic as they are splitting field of same irreducible polynomial over two isomorphic fields ( right ? ) , on second page .

But after it how are we writing
$$[L(\alpha):K]=[L(\beta ):K]$$ ?

Why didn't we directly wrote $[L(\alpha):L]=[L(\beta ):L]$ ,as both $L(\alpha)$ and$L(\beta)$ are isomorphic and extension of L ?

Comment: Why would we directly write that? What purpose would it serve?

Comment: Okay i edited my question i wanted to write L instead of K !

Comment: @Rishi Can I know the name of the book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know a priori that $L(\alpha)$ and $L(\beta)$ are isomorphic extensions of $L$. This is exactly what we are trying to prove: we have that $L(\alpha) = L$, because we assume that $\alpha$ belongs to $L$, and we are trying to prove that any other root $\beta$ of the minimal polynomial $m \in K[x]$ of $\alpha$ over $K$ also belongs to $L$, so that $m \in K[x]$ must in fact split into linear factors over $L$.

Consider, for example, $K = \mathbb{Q}$, and $L = K(\sqrt[3]{2})$, and let $\alpha = \sqrt[3]{2}$. Then, minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K = \mathbb{Q}$ is $m(x) = x^3 - 2$. The splitting field $M$ of $m$ is *not* $L$. Let $\beta$ be one of the complex roots of $x^3 - 2$. Then, $L(\alpha) = L$, but $L(\beta) \ne L$.

What might have confused you, though, is that we do easily know that $K(\alpha)$ and $K(\beta)$ are isomorphic extensions of $K$, because they are both isomorphic to the quotient ring $K[x]/(m)$ via maps $x \mapsto \alpha$ and $x \mapsto \beta$.

Comment: Ok i got $L(\alpha)$ and $L(\beta)$ are isomorphic but then how we writing $[L(\alpha):K]=[L(\beta ):K]$ ? As proof says using tower law what exactly is that law ? How we wrote K as lower field both sides ?

Comment: The proof observes that  $L(\alpha)/K(\alpha)$ is isomorphic to $L(\beta)/K(\beta)$, so $[L(\alpha):K(\alpha)] = [L(\beta):K(\beta)]$. We also know that $[K(\alpha):K] = [K(\beta):K]$. Multiply these two equalities, and apply tower law on both sides.

Comment: Okay so let me get this straight , if K/F and L/F are any two isomorphic field extensions of F then they have same degree over F . It seems obvious but How do we prove it ?

Comment: The degree $[K:F]$ of an extension $K/F$ is the dimension of $K$ as $F$-vector space. Let $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ be any basis of $K$ over F. Let $\phi: K \to L$ be isomorphism that's constant on $F$ (that's what it means to say that $K/F$ and $L/F$ are isomorphic extensions. Then $\phi(v_1), \ldots, \phi(v_n)$ is a basis of $L$ over $F$, so $\dim_F(L) = [L : F] = n$ as well.